# Ajax call to a Webservice Aways Fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, wcf

I am trying to make a simple web API call inside an HTML page using ajax (on button click). but that call always fail. Issue is only with ajax (on button click) call for that API. loading in combobox works perfectly fine. So, I hope it should not be a cross domain issue.

Following is the code where it causing trouble:

```
<body>

    <a class="offline-button" href="../index.html">Back</a>
    <input id="btnSayHello" type="button" value="Get Value From Ajax" /><br />

    <div id="example" class="k-content">

        <div class="demo-section">
            <h2>Products</h2>
            <input id="products" style="width: 250px" />
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
                    //dataTextField: "Name",
                    //dataValueField: "Name",
                    dataTextField: "ProductName",
                    dataValueField: "ProductID",
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $(function () {

                $("#btnSayHello").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "jsonp",
                        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataTypes: "jsonp",
                        processdata: true,
                        data: {},
                        url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("Success");
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            window.alert(result.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
```

For button click's Ajax call's *responseText* it returns "undefined"

Same URL call for Document ready function works fine. and populate that *ComboBox*.

SOURCE CODE can be found at this [link](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=CB9B95B4DD4D63A6&id=CB9B95B4DD4D63A6!2050).

Thanks everyone in advance for your help!

Comment: We won't go download and debug your project. *You* will need to pinpoint the source of the error and show relevant code here. _"I hope it should not be a cross domain issue"_ - what have you done to verify this? Try [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to inspect the request and response, look in your browser's console to see what is going on.

Comment: Please show the code and explain in what way it fails.  Does it not make the AJAX call at all?  Does the server respond with an error?  Is there a JavaScript error?

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster and David. I've updated original content. There is no javascript error. But calling that function calls returns to error function in script. Plz let me know if required more inputs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got my answer and the problem is because of "**dataTypes**" keyword. I changed it to "**dataType**" and it worked.

Well, I am new to web technologies and initially I tried to develop the same code in aspx page where "dataTypes" works just fine. Therefore, I tried to use same code base in a normal HTML file and it didn't work.

So, the conclusion is there might be some different treatment for "**dataTypes**" in **aspx** pages as compare to **HTML5**.

Answer (score 1):

you can see this,i think it solves your issue,try to send some duplicate value as queryparam by using callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btnSayHello").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products?callback=123",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("Success"+JSON.stringify(data));
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                           alert("error:"+result.responseText);
                        }
                    });


        });
      });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nPeaV/7370/

Comment: Yes, indeed it solves the issue. Can you please help me to understand the root cause. So that I can avoid doing it in future.
one thing I noticed is you have explicitly definieed in document ready function. Though, I am not really very much sure of that what change does it make. and secondly, you have added "?callback=123" what does that implies? Though, it running fine without that(duplicate callback values) as well, Only need to change that "Document Ready thingi stuff". Thanks for your time and help again..