# Jquery Ajax cross Domain returns success as status in error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing a cross domain get using jquery ajax but i get success as status in the error function.
I am expecting data to be returned from the `get` service is :

```
document.write("<div class=\"display_archive\"><div class=\"campaign\">07\/18\/2013 - <a href=\"http:\/\/us6.campaign-archive2.com\/?u=c7b9b2f23eb4f63fgfgf5ac4f&id=99e1f5f249\" title=\" Newsletter #3\" target=\"_blank\">Newsletter #3<\/a><\/div>");
```

but what i get is in `error function`

```
Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"}
```

My code

```
getResource : function ( containerSelector,serviceURL ) {
    $.ajax ({
        type : "GET",

        dataType: 'jsonp',

        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',

        url : serviceURL,

        headers : {
            "Accept" : "application/json",
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },

        success : function successData(resourceObj) {
            console.log("success ");
            console.log(resourceObj);
        },

        error : function errorData(resourceObj) {
            console.log("error ");
            console.log(resourceObj);
        },

    })
},
```

Am i missing something here ? help please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956854/ajax-call-to-a-webservice-aways-fails/18958068#18958068

Comment: Yes, you're missing the error parameter (it's the 3rd parameter passed to the error callback.)

Comment: using json padding as data-type, AJAX **error:** function will not be called.

Comment: @ram but... it is being called. In some circumstances it does still get called.

Comment: @KevinB the resource object gets me the whole object from the server do i still need to pass extra parameters ? however the issue is why does it not returns me the data ?

Comment: @KevinB.. Also note the data i am expecting is not json but it is text/html

Comment: @inputError Yes, the third parameter will give you jQuery's error message. It will tell you what (if anything) jQuery thinks the problem is. If you're expecting text/html, jsonp is not the correct dataType, therefore jQuery will send you to the error callback with the third parameter set to "parseerror" because it couldn't parse the response as json.

Comment: @KevinB i see. If datatype is not jsonp then how would i be able to make a cross domain call?

Comment: you can't. simple as that. You either must use JSONP, implement CORS, use iFrame postmessages, or use a server-side proxy. The only method out of those methods that can be done without changing the service-server is the server-side proxy.

Comment: @KevinB I cant control what the server sends so there is no way out?

Comment: Yes, a server-side proxy is your only way out if you have no control over the remote server. Make a service on your server that requests data from the remote server, and have your javascript request from the service on your server. `javascript -> your server -> remote server -> your server -> javascript`

Comment: @KevinB . Thanks Kevin will try to implement that

Comment: @KevinB ah you beat me to it - server side proxy is the way to go, JSONP is a nasty hack at best and using a server-side proxy instantly cuts out all cross domain BS plus gives a chance to transform the data in cases when it's not even the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSONP](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/) for `Cross-domain requests`

because Cross-domain requests are not directly allowed.  However, there is a commonly-used technique called [JSONP](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/) that will allow you to avoid this restriction through the use of script tags.  Basically, you create a callback function with a known name:

```
function getData(data) {       
}
```

And then your server wraps JSON data in a function call, like this:

```
getData({"the": "data"});
```

And you "call" the cross-domain server by adding a `script` tag to your page.  jQuery elegantly wraps all of this up in its `ajax` function.

Another technique that I've had to use at times is cross-document communication through iframes.  You can have one window talk to another, even cross-domain, in a restricted manner through [postMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771).  Note that only recent browsers have this functionality, so that option is not viable in all cases without resorting to hackery.

[Refrence 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)

[Refrence 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
crossDomain: true,
```

I can't see any error here other than that.

Comment: that parameter is very rarely ever needed. If this indeed is a cross-domain request, that parameter is already set to true.